# Chanson en laisse : Trois petits chats ?

Tags: paroles-de-chanson, comparaison-de-langues

Il y a une célèbre chanson en français, [Trois petits chats](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trois_petits_chats), construite sur un modèle où la première syllabe de chaque vers reprend la dernière du vers précédent :

> Trois p'tits chats, trois p'tits chats, trois p'tits chats, chats,
>   chats,
>
> Chapeau d'paille, chapeau d'paille, chapeau d'paille, paille,
>   paille,
>
> Paillasson, paillasson, paillasson, -son, -son,
>
> Somnambule,
>   somnambule, somnambule, -bule, -bule,
>
> ...

On appelle parfois de telles chansons des [chansons en laisse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chanson_en_laisse), même si la terminologie n'est pas forcément établie. Ce que j'entends par là, c'est une chanson où le début de chaque vers reprend la (ou les) syllabe(s) de fin du vers suivant, indépendamment du sens. Cela diffère d'un cas comme celui de [*À la claire fontaine*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%80_la_claire_fontaine).

Ce qui me surprend, c'est que j'ai eu beau chercher, je n'ai pas réussi à trouver d'équivalent de ces chansons dans d'autres langues. Je peux comprendre que, dans des langues à accent tonique ou à voyelles longues et brèves comme l'anglais, la mélodie de la chanson aurait du mal à convenir pour tous les mots ; mais je ne vois pas pourquoi d'autres langues syllabiques sans accent tonique ne pourraient pas avoir de telles chansons.

Qu'est-ce que la *laisse* de la *chanson en laisse* et quelle est généralement l'origine du procédé ? À quel sous-type de chanson en laisse pourrait correspondre *Trois petits chats* vu la différence avec *À la claire fontaine* ; chanson en laisse est-il le bon terme ici ; y a-t-il un parallèle à établir avec la présentation en *vers sénaires* ? Le français a-t-il une caractéristique particulière qui fait que le procédé employé avec la première chanson y fonctionne mieux qu'avec d'autres langues ?

Edit: En plus des chansons, il y a différentes langues disposant de *jeux* consistant à faire de tels enchaînements, comme le [shiritori](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiritori) (voir aussi [ceci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiritori#Similar_games)). Ça me semble différent des chansons ou poèmes, cependant.

Comment: Cela fait (en tout cas faisait) partie des jeux d'apprentissage des cours de récréation, dans le but d'enrichir le vocabulaire. Le plus connu (et pas chanté) est *Marabout, bout de ficelle, selle de cheval, cheval de bois, bois sans soif ... et là les difficultés commençaient pour celui qui devait trouver une suite, cela se terminait en rires ou railleries ; mais si le premier enjeu était de rebondir sur le  dernier mot  (ou la dernière syllabe s'il n'y a qu'un mot) sans en utiliser un déjà cité, le second était de choisir des terminaisons 'impossibles'.....

Comment: ..... Il serait surprenant que ce jeu soit uniquement francophone ! Peut-être n'est-il pas chanté, mais dans les écoles maternelles (ou dans la mémoire des grands parents) il serait étonnant qu'il n'y ait pas de comptines (qui sont plus ou moins chantées) qui fonctionnent de la sorte.

Comment: C'est pas tout à fait ce que tu cherches, mais en japonais, ils ont un jeu sur le même principe qui s'appelle le shiritori, qui consiste à enchainer des mots à partir de la fin du précédent. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiritori

Comment: Cette question ne porte pas sur la langue française mais sur d'autres langues. La question est à poser sur les autres sites de langues de SE.

Comment: Il aurait été plus pertinent de demander ce qu'est une « chanson en laisse ». La chanson en laisse fait partie de la versification française et a son origine dans la chanson de geste (Moyen-Âge français). 
« Une laisse est le groupement de plusieurs vers isométriques à assonances ou à rimes identiques en séries de longueur différente dépourvues d'articulation interne » (Traité de versification française des origines à nos jours - W. Theodor Elwert). Le sens du mot « laisse » ici est à rapprocher de celui de son sens dans l'expression « d'une laisse ».

Comment: @Laure: Pour le terme "chanson en laisse", j'utilise celui-ci faute de mieux : j'ai édité la question pour préciser ce que je veux dire. Pour le fait que ça ne porte pas vraiment sur le français : je suis un peu d'accord, mais vu que ce type de chansons n'existe qu'en français à ma connaissance, je me voyais mal poser la question un par un sur les autres sites, pour des langues que je ne connais pas. D'où ma reformulation de la question comme "qu'est-ce qui fait que le français se prête bien à ça" ?

Comment: Je ne suis pas spécialiste de la question mais la terminologie « chanson en laisse » me semble bien établie et la question du rapport au français est il me semble traitée dans plusieurs ouvrages de poétique (par exemple celui de [Conrad Laforte](https://books.google.fr/books?id=3Przqqd5XO8C&pg=PA19&lpg=PA19&dq=%22chanson+en+laisse%22&source=bl&ots=81kPC2dKe0&sig=ga2plJ8cStgoizwec0iBeEFr1ys&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBmoVChMIjajU8IPJxwIVx10aCh0xvgBF#v=onepage&q=%22chanson%20en%20laisse%22&f=false)).

Comment: @Laure: Ma question ne porte pas sur les "chansons en laisse" au sens de la poétique "groupement de plusieurs vers isométriques à assonances ou à rimes identiques en séries de longueur différente dépourvues d'articulation interne", mais sur la "chanson au laisse" au sens où je le définis dans la question, "chanson où le début de chaque vers reprend la (ou les) syllabe(s) de fin du vers suivant". Peut-être que j'ai tort d'utiliser le terme "chanson en laisse" pour désigner ça ; s'il existe un meilleur terme, ça m'intéresserait ! :)

Comment: Ce que tu décris s'appelle bien « chanson en laisse » et si tu suis le lien que je te donnais dans mon message tu verras en quoi ce que tu décris est exactement, au sens de la poétique (la forme chanson fait partie de la poétique) la suite des chansons en laisse des chansons de geste du Moyen-Âge.

Comment: I’ve played the game described by @c-lr, most often on long road trips here in the US as a child.  We had to repeat the full previous word (not the previous syllable), which perhaps made our game more of an exercise “in anadiplosis” than of one “en laisse.” The Wanted’s “[Glad You Came](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/wanted/gladyoucame.html)” contains some anadiplosis: “Turn the lights out now//Now I'll take you by the hand//Hand you another drink//Drink it if you can//Can you spend a little time,//Time is slipping away,//Away from us so stay,//Stay with me I can make,//Make you glad you came”

Comment: @RiguefortUltraquaillette: OK pour réouvrir. J'ai pensé à demander sur English Language and Usage, mais ça ne me semble pas non plus dans le scope, vu que la question ne parlerait pas à proprement parler de la langue anglaise https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: N'y a-t-il pas dans les répertoires folkloriques (et particulièrement breton) ce genre de chansons où l'animateur lance sa phrase qui ensuite complètement ou partiellement reprise en cœur par l'assistance ?

Answer (score 3):

[On](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14828/chanson-en-laisse-trois-petits-chats#comment28418_14828) a [dit](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14828/chanson-en-laisse-trois-petits-chats#comment28420_14828) que la chanson en laisse fait partie de la versification française et a son origine dans la [chanson de geste](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chanson_de_geste) (Moyen-Âge français). « Une laisse est le groupement de plusieurs vers isométriques à assonances ou à rimes identiques en séries de longueur différente dépourvues d'articulation interne » ([*Traité de versification française des origines à nos jours*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZXpfAAAAMAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22isom%C3%A9triques%20%C3%A0%20assonances%22) - W. Theodor Elwert). Le sens du [mot](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/laisse/45962?q=laisse#45897) « [laisse](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZXpfAAAAMAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22laisse%22) » ici est à rapprocher de celui de son sens dans l'expression « [d'une laisse](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZXpfAAAAMAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22une%20laisse%22) ».

La terminologie « chanson en laisse » semble bien établie et la question du rapport au français est, il semble, traitée dans plusieurs ouvrages de poétique (par exemple celui de [*Conrad Laforte*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=3Przqqd5XO8C&pg=PA19&lpg=PA19&dq=%22chanson%20en%20laisse%22&source=bl&ots=81kPC2dKe0&sig=ga2plJ8cStgoizwec0iBeEFr1ys&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBmoVChMIjajU8IPJxwIVx10aCh0xvgBF#v=onepage&q=%22chanson%20en%20laisse%22&f=false)). La chanson qu'on présente (*Trois petits chats*) constitue, au sens de la poétique (la forme chanson fait partie de la poétique), la suite des chansons en laisse des chansons de geste du Moyen-Âge.

---

Par ailleurs, si elle dispose de vers de même longueur, ceux-ci n'ont ni une rime ni une assonance commune comme dans *À la claire fontaine* ; à moins de remanier chaque vers en trois partie (*trois p'tits chats* - *trois p'tits chats* - *trois p'tits chats, chats, chats*) et de dire qu'il s'agit de 36 laisses de trois vers et que normalement on nous présente une forme secondaire sur une ligne. Mais ainsi découpés les vers ne sont plus isométriques (3-3-5).

La figure de style consistant en la répétition d'une syllabe finale au début de vers suivant est celle de l'[anadiplose](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anadiplose) (voir aussi, plus spécifiquement, [*dorica castra*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dorica_castra)). L'association que fait l'ébauche d'article *Wikipedia* entre la chanson en laisse et cette répétition semble [erronée](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discussion:Chanson_en_laisse) puisque la laisse est un regroupement de vers ; l'inclusion de *Trois petits chats* dans la liste est à tout le moins suspecte. Quant au vers [sénaire](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/s%C3%A9naire), il se divise en *six mesures rythmiques*. Comme on l'a vu, la définition ne fait pas appel à ce concept ; dans [*À la claire fontaine*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%80_la_claire_fontaine), la rime commune (/e/) s'analyse sur un alexandrin et la division en une forme secondaire hexasyllabique nuit à l'identification de la laisse.

Comment: Intéressant ! Plus spécifiquement, la figure de style utilisée dans *Trois petits chats* semble s'appeler le "dorica castra" https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dorica_castra

Answer (score 2):

La version plus générique existe en tamil : "Andhadhi is a form of poem in Tamil literature, in which the last word of the previous verse forms the starting word of the next verse."

Source : description d'un appli gratuit disponsible à Amazon : [Kambar - Sadagopar Andhadhi](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00XMPE1FA)

En anglais, elle s'appelle « chain verse » ou bien « chain rhyme » : "A descendant of Ancient Greek echo verse, chain verse uses the same closing word or syllable from one line to open the next line."

Source : [Chain Verse at a Glance](http://www.webexhibits.org/poetry/explore_obscure_chain_atglance.html)

Comment: Merci ! En particulier l'exemple "Mothering" sur http://www.webexhibits.org/poetry/explore_obscure_chain_make.html est intéressant parce qu'on ne répète que la sonorité, et pas un mot entier, donc on n'a pas d'exigence de continuité au niveau du sens.

Answer (score 0):

Ce n'est pas la même chose, mais cette question m'a fait penser à une chanson enfantine assez impolie, où la fin de chaque quatrain semble grossier jusqu'à ce que le premier mot du suivant quatrain se révèle.

```
Miss Susie had a steamboat,
the steamboat had a bell.
Miss Susie went to heaven
the steamboat went to hell–

o, Operator,
give me number nine.
If you should disconnect me
I'll blow off your be–

hind the refrigerator,
there was a piece of glass,
Miss Susie sat upon it
and broke her little

Ask me no more questions,
tell me no more lies.
The boys are in the girls' room,
pulling down their

Flies are in the kitchen,
bees are in the park.
And boys and girls are kissing
in the D-A-R-K
D-A-R-K
D-A-R-K
dark, dark, dark!
```

Comment: [La version de South Park](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8X1kPxhB2zQ).